# Java Linked List unable to add item to end

Tags: java, list, queue

Can't seem to add a last element properly. I hold the last item in a temp node, then create a new node. Then I link both previous and next for each node, then point the last node to a new null node. But that null node doesn't seem to be part of the list when I go to my print() method.

Seems like it should be as easy as my push method, but I just can't seem to get it work like it.

```
public class LinkedListDeque {

public DoubleNode first = new DoubleNode(null);
public DoubleNode last = new DoubleNode(null);
public DoubleNode temp;
public int N;

LinkedListDeque() {
    first.next = last;
    last.prev = first;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    LinkedListDeque link = new LinkedListDeque();

    link.push("banana");
    link.printList();

    link.enqueue("gorilla");
    link.printList();


    link.enqueue("spam");

}


//nested class

private class DoubleNode {

    String item;
    int counter = 0;
    DoubleNode next;
    DoubleNode prev;

    DoubleNode(String i) {
        this.item = i;
    }

}

public void push(String item) {

    System.out.println("\npush()\n******");
    if (first.item == null) {
        first.item = item;
        first.counter++;
    } else {

        System.out.println("last.item = " + last.item);
        DoubleNode node = new DoubleNode(item);
        first.prev = node;
        node.next = first;
        first = node;

    }

}



 public void enqueue(String item) {
    System.out.println("\nenqueue()\n***********");
    System.out.println("adding \"" + item + "\" to the end");

    if (last.item == null) {
        DoubleNode node = new DoubleNode(null);                     //holds null node to end list
        last.item = item;
        last.next = node;
    } else {
        DoubleNode node = new DoubleNode(null);
        System.out.println("node = " + node.item);                  //= correct item

        temp = last;
        last = new DoubleNode(item);                                //creating a new last node

        System.out.println("temp = " + temp.item);                  //corect
        //reconnect the links
        temp.next.item = last.item;

        System.out.println("temp.prev = " + temp.prev.item);        //correct
        System.out.println("temp.next = " + temp.next.item);        //correct
        System.out.println("last = " + last.item);                  //correct
        System.out.println("last.prev = " + last.prev);             //correct

        last.prev = temp;

        System.out.println("last.prev = " + last.prev.item);        //correct

        last.next = node;
        System.out.println("last.next = " + last.next.item);        //= null to end list

        System.out.println("\n\nfirst = " + first.item);                                //correct
        System.out.println("first.next = " + first.next.item);                          //correct
        System.out.println("first.next.next = " + first.next.next.item);                //correct
        System.out.println("first.next.next.next = " + first.next.next.next.item);      //"null pointer exception"
}

public void printList() {
    System.out.println("\nprintList():\n********");
    temp = first;

    int i = 0;
    if (first.item == null) {
        temp = first.next;
    }
    System.out.println("temp = " + temp.item);
    while (temp.item != null) {
        i++;
        System.out.println(i + " " + temp.item);
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Why does the `enqueue` method contain print statements?

Comment: Your `first` node and `last` node are being treated as two separate lists, where `last` is the first node of its own list. You need to link up the `last` and `first` nodes when you add the first node into the list.

Comment: To add a new node at the end of a circular doubly linked list. First you need to create a new node. Set previous of new node to last node and next to head. The next step is to set next of last node to new node and set previous of head to new node.

Comment: @arcadeblast77 to test whether or not the intention of each line of code is doing what I want it to do.

Comment: @Travelsbyfire Using a debugger is way better. Get comfortable with it.

Comment: @MihirKekkar I'm keeping a null node at the end because that's how my list will determine where the end should be I guess.

Comment: @Goion It's not a circular doubly linked list

Comment: @Goion probably, but I've never used one, so I'm not sure where I'd even begin

Comment: When you add your very first node to the list, `first` and `last` should hold the same node because the first and last element would both be the one you have just added. In your `push()`, you are only assigning the first node to `first`, so `last` never actually gets connected to the list. Hence when you print out the whole list starting from `first`, it won't be able to access nodes linked from `last`.

Comment: this is a good start [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Suggestion. Take a paper and pen and draw a step by step diagram of what should happen. It would help you a lot. I had an assignment where I had to insert node in doubly circular list sorted. Drawing helped me a lot.

Comment: @Goion thanks, I'll definitely check that out, get's tiring to keep writing system.out.println(); haha

Comment: @Goion, Yeah I've been drawing it constantly, that's how I came up with this code, but drawing abstract maybe doesn't work well for me, idk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see what is actually happening:
the initial state:

- first contains null, first.next is last, last contains null
- push: first does not contain null any more, still points to last,with null
- enque: last.item is null, so the first cae is triggered, now the list is like: banana -> gorilla -> null and last points to gorilla
- enque again: now the else is triggered. If you have a look at the code, you
  will notice that temp.next is not touched anywhere. This means that the node that was the last node before the enque,and was copied to temp still points to the null node.
- this finally results in a null pointer exception.

What is missing: something like `temp.next=last`, after the last node is created.

What actually happens looks like this:

```
---> last ---> closing-null

---> temp ---> closing-null

---> last
```

It seems you could implement this more cleanly without the null nodes closing the list.

Then you could do something like this:

```
node=new Node(item);
last.next=node;
node.prev=last;
last=node;
```

Comment: if they aren't connected, why would first.next.next = last?

Comment: Yes, in fact the interlinking is missing in some other places, like the last null node prev is not  added anywhere in enque.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but at the very top, first.next = last

Comment: So the only problem I have with this code is that I still get a null pointer exception. I can't even understand why though

Comment: But I do have the temp.next. item = last.item as the first thing I do to reconnect the links

Comment: temp.next.item is the string contained in the node pointed by temp.next. That is the item that had the null pointer previously. The temp.next pointer is not updated, so it is still pointing to the item that was the closing null item in the previous version of the queue. You update it's content, but it gets detached from the list, and it points to nowhere. You can not reach last any more from first after the else ran. Does that make sense?

Comment: oh hell yeah, it was just that one single bit of code. I just changed it to temp.next = last and now it works perfectly. Idk why I thought I needed to change the value

Answer (score 1):

I won't give you the whole code but I will visualize it. You can come up with code easily after this.

Next is `--->` and Previous is `<---` and last points towards last node and first towards first node

Lets say you have this list.

```
Banana ---> Orange ---> Gorilla ---> null
       <---        <---         
  ^                       ^
  |                       |
first                    last
// First's previous and last's next is null.
```

You want to add Mango at the end.
You create a new node

```
DoubleNode node = new DoubleNode("Mango");
<--- Mango --->
// Note: When you create a new node by default both next and previous are null. 
// You don't need to point them to null later
```

Step 1:

```
last.next(newNode);
Banana ---> Orange ---> Gorilla ---> Mango 
       <---        <---    
  ^                       ^
  |                       |
first                    last
```

Step 2:

```
newNode.previous(last);
Banana ---> Orange ---> Gorilla ---> Mango 
       <---        <---         <---
  ^                       ^
  |                       |
first                    last
```

Now we have new last so we will update last

```
last = newNode
Banana ---> Orange ---> Gorilla ---> Mango 
       <---        <---         <---
  ^                                    ^
  |                                    |
first                                last
```

From constructor we know Mango's next is already null
so `newNode.next(null);` is unnecessary.

> Reasons you could be getting nullpointerexception

After adding first element your list looks like this

```
null <--- Banana ---> null      null
             ^                   ^
             |                   |
           first                last
```

Technically you should make both first and last point towards banana since you don't. When you enqueue something it would be let's say gorilla. It would be

```
null.item = "Gorilla"
null.next = null
```

Comment: So would (first.next =  last) and (last.prev = first;) make sure that both first and last are pointing to banana?

Comment: @Travelsbyfire It is up to you. If you do that your list would become circular. You could just point last towards banana and it would fix issue. If your last is null assume that your list is completely empty.

Comment: @Travelsbyfire Even after pointing last towards banana the algo I gave in answer to enqueue would still work.

Comment: yeah it totally makes sense. g_bor actually pointed out to me the line temp.next.item = last.item didn't actually change my node, rather the pointer, and after changing that line to temp.next = last, it stopped giving me the null pointer exception.

Comment: @Travelsbyfire Right`temp.next.item = last.item;` temp points towards last element. Its next would return `null`.

Comment: Thanks for the illustration, this stuff gets really confusing quickly without something like that, ive decided to include mango in my arbitrary variable values

Comment: @Travelsbyfire Nice one